# Creating NuGet package with project referencies

Tags: nuget, symbols

We have following solution structure:

```
Solution
--Project1
--Project2
...
```

In Project 2 are interfaces. Project 1 has reference on Project 2. We are building the package with Nuget.exe as follows:

```
NuGet.exe Pack Project1.csproj -Symbols
```

What we get are two packages, one with sources and pdb's other only with assemblies. But what is missing are sources, pdb's and assemblies from other project, Project 2. If we are adding this manually (what is pretty tedious work) we can upload symbols package to Symbol Server.

What are we doing wrong? Is it necessary that we build NuGet package also from Project 2 and make the Project 1 depend from this project (what will be also pretty tedious work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a package for Project 2 and add it as a dependent package for Project 1. I have raised an [issue](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2825) for it to see if there are ways to optimize it.

Thanks

Bhuva